# Which framework, server or software is recommended to create website?

Tags: framework

I have a need to crate a website. Which framework, server or software is recommended to create website?
I will have need to use database.

Let me clarify: I am looking for a tool/framework, that will have predefined components that will allow me to build website efficiently. Please recommend tools for beginners. I am expecting average db size, preferably MySQL, Website would be chat-blog like application, with functionality to crate topics/questions, and interact with it: like write comments or answers.

Thank you

Comment: I think this is a too broad request. There are too many different options. What kind of website do you want to build? How many users will it have? What database size do you expect? Do you want free software or don't you mind paying? What programming languages are you familiar with, or don't you want to program at all? Does the website need user management/login feature? How do you want it to be hosted? Do you already have a provider or not?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Please recommend tools for beginners. I am expecting average db size, preferably MySQL, Website would be chat-blog like application, with functionality to crate topics/questions, and interact with it: like write comments or answers.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a tool/framework, that will have predefined components that will allow me to build website efficiently. Please recommend tools for beginners. I am expecting average db size, preferably MySQL, Website would be chat-blog like application, with functionality to crate topics/questions, and interact with it: like write comments or answers.

Have you looked at [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/)? We even have a [site for Drupal questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/).

It is ***very*** widely used, mature, stable, well documented and has lots of support.

You can build a website from scratch, or, as a beginner, choose an existing [theme / template](https://themeforest.net/category/cms-themes/drupal).

It has thousands of plug-ins (onown as modules), like shopping carts, multi-language support, etc, so I would be very surprised if it did not have one for your blog/chat functionality (I seem to recall doing something similar, but that was 10 years ago, so my memory is hazy).

> As of December 2019 the Drupal website lists more than 44,000 free modules. Core modules include Blogs, books, comments, forums, and polls.

Take a look at the [Drupal chat](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalchat) plugin.

> DrupalChat allows visitors of your Drupal site to chat with each other privately or together in a public chatroom. This module enables sites to provide online support for their products/services, and thereby increases user engagement. Also, it is useful for social networking sites, forums, blogs, etc. It logs the user conversations so that they can be later viewed in message inbox. You can try it out live [here](https://www.iflychat.com/help/integration/drupal/install-drupal-chat-module?refid=drupal).